If a Matrix represents injective directional derivation form of $df(p)$, then a Matrix B such that $det$([$df(p)$ $B$]) $≠$ $0$ exists?
Lemma 2. 1. 10
My question is start from this sentence; "If a Matrix $A[df(p)]$ is injective linear transformation, which represents directional derivation form of df(p), then a Matrix B, such that $det$([$A$[$df(p)$]$B$]) ≠ 0 exists?"
▪︎first, this theorem is here.
Let m and k be integers with 0 ≤ m ≤ k.
Let $M$ ⊂ $\mathbf R$
k
be a set and $p_0$ ∈ $M$. Then the following are equivalent.
(i) There exists an M-open neighborhood $U_0$ ⊂ $M$ of $p_0$ and a diffeomorphism
$φ_0$ : $U_0$ → $Ω_0$ onto an open set $Ω_0$ ⊂ $\mathbf R^{m}$.
(ii) There exist open sets $U$, $Ω$ ⊂ $\mathbf R$
k and a diffeomorphism $φ$ : $U$ → $Ω$ such
that $p_0$ ∈ $U$ and
$φ$($U$ $∩$ $M$) = $Ω$ $∩$ ($\mathbf R^{m}$ × {$0$})
(iii) There exists an open set $U$ ⊂ $\mathbf R$
k and a smooth map $f$ : $U$ → $\mathbf R^{k−m}$
such that $p_0$ ∈ $U$, the derivative $df(p)$ : $\mathbf R^{k}$ → $\mathbf R^{k−m}$ is surjective for every
point p ∈ $U$ $∩$ $M$, and
$U$ $∩$ $M$ = $f^{−1}$($0$) = {$p$ ∈ U | $f(p)$ = $0$} .
Moreover, if (i) holds, then the diffeomorphism φ : $U$ → $Ω$ in (ii) can be
chosen such that $U$ $∩$ $M$ ⊂ $U0$ and $φ$($p$) = ($φ_0$($p$), $0$) for every p ∈ $U$ $∩$ $M$.

He said, "We prove that (i) implies (ii). Let $φ_0$ : $U_0$ → $Ω_0$ be the coordinate chart
in part (i), let $ψ_0$ $:=$ $φ_0^{−1}$
: $Ω_0$ → $U_0$ be its inverse, and let $x_0$ := $φ_0$($p_0$) ∈ $Ω_0$.
Then the derivative $dψ_0(x_0)$ : $\mathbf R^{m}$ → $\mathbf R^{k}$
k
is injective by Lemma 2.1.4. Hence
there exists a matrix $B$ $∈$ $\mathbf R^{k×(k−m)}$
such that $det$([$dψ_{0}$ $(x_0)$ $B$]) $≠$ $0$. Define
the map $ψ$ : $Ω_0$ $×$ $\mathbf R^{k−m}$ → $\mathbf R^{k}$ by
$ψ$($x$, $y$) := $ψ_0$($x$) + By.
Then the $k$ × $k$ -matrix $dψ$($x_0$, $0$) = [$dψ_{0}$($x_0$) $B$] ∈ $\mathbf R^{k×k}$ is nonsingular."
Then, I'm so curious about why above question is true although under sentences establish.
▪︎An injective linear transformation preserves non-zero vectors. This means if a non-zero vector goes into $A$[$df$ $(p)$], a non-zero vector comes out. So, Nullity subspace is only zero.
▪︎However, multiplying by another matrix $B$ can still affect the determinant. In particular, even if $B$ map the nonzero vector to zero, it could affect the scaling or orientation of the transformed vectors in a way that reduces the determinant to zero.
But, in my book, author told that determinant is not 0. I think this is an typo, or error of logic! Name of the author is Salamon. Thank you for visit.

If $m>n$ and $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix of rank $n$, then we must multiply by a $n\times m$ matrix $B$ in order for $\det(AB)$ to be defined. However, the determinant must be $0$, as the rank of the $m\times m$ $AB$ is at most $n$. The calculus is irrelevant, unless I’ve misunderstood your question.
